# SSD appears in UEFI BIOS but won't boot

Tags: boot, ssd, uefi

I have a PC with an Asus ROG Strix B350-F Gaming Motherboard with a Ryzen 5 2600 processor.

I have a 1TB Samsung NvME SSD on this PC (where Windows 10 is installed) along with a 250GB SATA SSD for additional storage.

I recently removed the 250GB SSD and replaced it with a 1TB Crucial SATA SSD.

After doing this, the PC goes straight into UEFI BIOS and won't boot into Windows. I checked the boot priority and both SSDs show up in the correct order. I tried a Boot Override into the NvME SSD but it goes straight back into the BIOS.

[image: bios boot priority]

I don't understand why the installation of an additional drive would affect the boot behavior on my main drive.

I tried some things like setting the BIOS settings to default and turning off Fast Boot, none of which worked.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to understand the UEFI mode boot process before anything else. The part about "drive order" shows you don't. UEFI boots from .efi files present in the ESP (EFI System Partition) that very likely was on the drive you replaced. This has nothing to do with the drive where the main OS partition resides, it can be the same or any other.

Comment: Okay, got it! I installed the old drive back in and it booted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive that was replaced contained the ESP (EFI System Partition). As expected, the current Windows installation cannot boot without it.

Reusing the old SSD made it boot as before.

The author now needs to plan any drive replacement considering the need for the ESP.